# Understanding gain of the DCT transform

Tags: dct, image-compression, jpeg

I have been reading the guide from:

- [JPEG Huffman Coding Tutorial](https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/jpeg-huffman-coding.html)

I eventually reached the point where it states:

> Finally, we want to convert the DCT DC value to an RGB value. Assuming
> that the gain of the DCT transform is 4, we divide the values by 4 to
> get block1 = -128, block2 = +127.

I have to admit, I do not understand where this magic value `'4'` is coming from. With the help of `djpeg` and `jpegtran`, I was able to craft two different JPEG files:

1. [white512.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTKco.jpg) ([image]) is a JPEG where the DC value is +512,
2. [white338.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqThz.jpg) ([image]) is a JPEG where the DC value is +338

Using a simple check, we can confirm they both decompress to the same white ppm file:

```
% djpeg -outfile 338.ppm white338.jpg
% djpeg -outfile 512.ppm white512.jpg 
% md5sum 338.ppm 512.ppm
18f695bae266c6a24506936dab1dfc23  338.ppm
18f695bae266c6a24506936dab1dfc23  512.ppm
```

Could someone please tell me:

1. Where is this value `'4'` value coming from ?
2. How come both the DC value 338 & 512 expand to the same white value (0xFF) ?

---

For reference, the JPEG files uploaded on `imgur` have been edited in my back. In particular the upload process strips the `APP0` marker. To get the exact same image as I have on disk, one can apply back the default `jpegtran` settings:

```
% jpegtran -outfile white512.jpg -optimize jTKco.jpg
% jpegtran -outfile white338.jpg -optimize WqThz.jpg
% md5sum white512.jpg white338.jpg
695527adb6b269214e38e45157edb256  white512.jpg
051434f11491bdf1c1be38ad8f69f5be  white338.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the small experiment I was able to conduct on my Debian system. I crafted two small $8 \times 8$ JPEG files again:

- white: ([image: white_1016.jpg])
- black: ([image: black_minus1024.jpg])

I used the following commands:

```
% convert -size 8x8 -depth 8 xc:white white.pgm
% convert -size 8x8 -depth 8 xc:black black.pgm
```

then:

```
% cjpeg -sample 1x1 -quality 100 -grayscale -outfile white.jpg white.pgm
% cjpeg -sample 1x1 -quality 100 -grayscale -outfile black.jpg black.pgm
```

Note that in this case, it is a single component JPEG (no color space transform):

```
% file white.jpg
white.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 8x8, components 1
```

Upon inspection, one can check that the DC coefficient stored in `white.jpg` is `1016`, while the DC coefficient stored in `black.jpg` is `-1024`. Which can also be represented as:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1016&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$

One can also check that the quantization table is simply a a bunch of ones:

```
% djpeg -verbose -verbose -outfile dummy.ppm white.jpg
[...]
Define Quantization Table 0  precision 0
           1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
           1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
           1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
           1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
           1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
           1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
           1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
           1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

So taking the entry-for-entry product with the quantization matrix from above results simply in the same matrix.

Going back to the equations on [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Decoding):

$$f_{x,y} =
 \frac{1}{4}
 \sum_{u=0}^7
 \sum_{v=0}^7
 \alpha(u) \alpha(v) F_{u,v}
 \cos \left[\frac{(2x+1)u\pi}{16} \right]
 \cos \left[\frac{(2y+1)v\pi}{16} \right]$$

Simply gives on our case (no rounding error):

$$f_{x,y} = 
\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}}1016\times 1+63\times 0\right) = 127$$

So adding 128 to each entries lead to:

$$\left[
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 \\
255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 \\
255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 \\
255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 \\
255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 \\
255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 \\
255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 \\
255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255 & 255
\end{array}
\right]$$

Repeating the above for the `black.jpg` image with DC value `-1024` gives:

$$f_{x,y} = 
\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}}\times -1024\times 1+63\times 0\right) = -128$$

Which is what we expected.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplied by the first value of the Quantization Table.

```
jpeg_component_info->quant_table->quantval[0]
```